# Convert unsigned char* to QString and vice versa

Tags: c++, windows, qt, qstring

I am trying to convert `const unsigned char*` to `QString` and vice versa. I have managed to convert it in one direction, but not from `QString` to `const unsigned char*`. I've seen a lot of similiar questions, but none of the solutions worked for me.

Here is my sample code :

```
void f(const unsigned char* addr)
{
 QString data = QString::fromLatin1((const char*)addr, len);  //should work correctly
 
 unsigned char* cc = new unsigned char[data.size()];
 memcpy(cc, data.toStdString().c_str(), data.size());   //isn't working
}
```

My check for a solution : `len = 8` in this example, therefore :

`data` contains :

[image: data content]

```
unsigned char buff[8];
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    buff[i] = cc[i];
//buff now contains [194,128,6,0,1,0,0,18]

unsigned char bb[8];
memcpy(bb, addr, 8);
//bb contains [128,6,0,1,0,0,18,0]
```

Is there any other way ? Thank you for any input.

Comment: Looks fine to me, what makes you say it isn't working?

Comment: I'm not 100% on `QString` but `memcpy(cc, data.toStdString().c_str(), data.toStdString().size());` seems like a more logical version of your code. If the size of QString and the corresponding standard string are different then your code is not going to work.

Comment: @john not sure but I think this also would not account for the null terminator. I'd rather suggest `strcpy`

Comment: @idclev463035818 I'm not seeing that the OP wants to copy the nul terminator, but I could be wrong.

Comment: In the code you posted there is no way to know if it "worked" or not. Perhaps you used a debugger, which would be good, but you need to tell us what makes you conclude that it "isn't working"

Comment: Knowing what constitutes working would also help, especially with regard to the nul terminator, which you might or might not want to copy.

Comment: I think you need to add a [mcve] maybe not accounting for the null terminator is the problem.

Comment: I did a simple checking. In my example, i know that the `addr` is not null terminated, and it may contain null characters. I also know that the size I want to copy is 8, so i created `unsigned char buff[8]` and copied via for loop content of `cc` and then `addr`. And they do not match. When copying from `cc`, buff contains `194,128,6,0,1,0,0,18` , and after copying from `addr` it contains `128,6,0,1,0,0,18,0`.

Comment: please add that code to the question ([mcve]) together with input, expected and actual output

Comment: in your comments it looks like off-by-one, hard to tell without seeing the code

Comment: @Peter This is impossible to follow, all the code you post looks fine, but it's all partial code. Post one piece of code that goes from given input to the unexpected output. Copy strings is not hard, you're making a mistake somewhere but it's not at all clear what that mistake is given the fragments of code you have posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here's a clue as to what is really going on. In your original string you have the byte sequence 194 128. That's a possible the encoding for the Euro symbol in UTF-8. In your output that has been replaced by the single byte 128, which is the encoding for the Euro symbol in the Windows-1252 code page.

So somewhere in your code there is a change of encoding happening, which explains why you see the difference in input and output. Almost certainly that change is happening because of one or other of the `QString` functions you are using.

Solving this problem is not really possible without know more about what you are actually doing. If your byte arrays do not represent text then it's a mistake to put them into a `QString` since these are used for *Unicode text* not arbitrary byte arrays.

Comment: QString stores the characters as 16 bit not sure if this is the cause of the problem. Related: [https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#details](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#details) maybe QByteArray is a better choice however I don't understand the reason for converting to QString in the first place.

Comment: It is true that my byte array `addr` doesn't represent text. I am reading a `.pcap` file, therefore `addr` represents data stream. What should I use than if not `QString` ?

Comment: Try `QByteArray` ***in addition to QString, Qt also provides the QByteArray class to store raw bytes and traditional 8-bit '\0'-terminated strings. For most purposes, QString is the class you want to use. It is used throughout the Qt API, and the Unicode support ensures that your applications will be easy to translate if you want to expand your application's market at some point. The two main cases where QByteArray is appropriate are when you need to store raw binary data, and when memory conservation is critical (like in embedded systems).***